# How do I compare a NSUserDefaults integer with another integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, nsuserdefaults

I'm a very new developer and I'm still getting to know my way around things but can somebody please show me how I would run code if the integer saved using NSUserDefaults is equal to 1.

I would normally use an "if" statement, but I understand you can't use == to compare NSUserDefaults. What can I do then? Where can I learn more about NSUserDefaults? I've looked through the Apple Docs but I get confused easily by it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` has an `integerForKey:` method, so you can get the integer and then use your `if` and `==` to make the comparison.

Comment: So should this work? Or is there something else to it? `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"myValue"];` `if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myValue"] == 1) {
        // Action
    }`

Comment: Yes, it should. Did you try it and have some issue?

Comment: Yes, it always comes back as 0. I put an NSLog after it and it shows 0. No idea why

Comment: @user2329585 synchronize after to add value.

Comment: @VinayakKini, synchronize shouldn't be required. It just pushes the default to disk but the value should still be set in memory. And the posted code works for me.

Comment: if data important for you, you have to synchronize, in case of app crashing

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I already had synchronise code in there. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` What could I possibly be doing wrong? I smell something wrong with my surrounding code but nothing I can see.

Comment: You'd need to post all of your code, as I say, the code you have posted in the comment above works for me.

Comment: I will take another look at my code and eliminate things slowly in order to hopefully narrow the fault down to a smaller piece of code but If that fails, I'll post it up and hope that someone sees something wrong with it. I won't be able to get to my computer until later though.

Comment: I found the problem. It's me! I made a stupid mistake in muddling up the keys. I have many different keys with similar names so I was putting the wrong one in all along even though I was checking to make sure that wouldn't happen. I'm embarrassed. I do apologise for taking your time! For your help I'll upvote Vinayak Kini's comment and mark the answer.